# R Rounding a Time

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a data frame with a series of times in the following format:

```
08:09:23.079

> class(timer3) 
[1] "factor"
```

I would like to round/convert them to this format:

```
08:09
```

The end goal is to use them as values for the x-axis of a plot so I assume they would need to go to some type of time format (zoo, as.Date, etc.).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Two steps: 

1) Factor to character: as.character()
2) character to POSIXct: strptime()

Comment: convert to character and look at `strptime()`

Comment: One of you guys want to slap your comment in an answer so I can choose it?

Comment: Why don't you just do it yourself? Another moderator already declined your previous flag saying we can't convert the comments to answers for you.

Comment: @mweylandt: can you put your comment in an answer so I can choose it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps: 1) Factor to character: as.character() 2) character to POSIXct: strptime()

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have this input data:

```
DF <- data.frame(times = c("08:09:23.079", "08:30:13.062"), values = 1:2)
```

To keep it simple lets assume that there is *at most one time point per minute* (we show an alternative that is slightly longer afterwards without this restriction):

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)

# this assumes we want to store times to the second
tt <- times(as.character(DF$times))
z <- zoo(DF$values, tt)

plot(z, xaxt = "n")

# custom axis - assumes sufficiently many points to get reasonable graph
# round tick mark locations to the minute and remove the seconds from label
axt <- trunc(times(axTicks(1)), "min")
axis(1, at = axt, lab = sub(":..$", "", axt))
```

The above method of creating z could alternately be replaced with this. It works whether or not there is more than one point per minute as it aggregates them to the minute:

```
# with this z we will be store times to the minute
z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = function(x) trunc(times(as.character(x)), "min"), 
      aggregate = mean)
```

EDIT:  plotting and truncation.

Answer (score 3):

At risk of being called necromancer, I will answer this question as I think this situation arises quite often.

Here is how to do it if you convert your timeseries data in `xts` format. The function to be used here is `align.time`

```
> head(GBPJPY)
                    GBPJPY.Open GBPJPY.High GBPJPY.Low GBPJPY.Close
2009-05-01 00:14:59     146.387     146.882    146.321      146.620
2009-05-01 00:29:54     146.623     146.641    146.434      146.579
2009-05-01 00:44:59     146.579     146.908    146.570      146.810
2009-05-01 00:59:59     146.810     146.842    146.030      146.130
2009-05-01 01:14:59     146.130     146.330    146.100      146.315
2009-05-01 01:29:57     146.315     146.382    146.159      146.201
> head(align.time(GBPJPY, 15*60))
                    GBPJPY.Open GBPJPY.High GBPJPY.Low GBPJPY.Close
2009-05-01 00:15:00     146.387     146.882    146.321      146.620
2009-05-01 00:30:00     146.623     146.641    146.434      146.579
2009-05-01 00:45:00     146.579     146.908    146.570      146.810
2009-05-01 01:00:00     146.810     146.842    146.030      146.130
2009-05-01 01:15:00     146.130     146.330    146.100      146.315
2009-05-01 01:30:00     146.315     146.382    146.159      146.201
```

Answer (score 2):

```
as.zoo(sapply(timer3,substring,1,5))
or as.xts?
```

Maybe looking at a bigger sample of your data would help.